# check if a folder is empty (internal storage)

Tags: android, filesystems, directory

I've the sequent trouble. My app should read a list of files and show their name to the user.
When the app is launched for the first time i need to create a specific folder for the app?
then how can i check if it's empty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you created the directory in the internal storage, you can get the number of child objects in the directory like this

```
File dir = context.getDir("somePath", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
File[] children = dir.listFiles();
if(children.length > 0)
{
    // the directory is not empty
}
else
{
    // the directory is empty.
}
```

This is just a quick sample code. The better way would be to exclude the self and parent aliases using a custom `FileFilter` with `dir.listFiles()`, as I'm not sure they will always be excluded from the resulting list.

Answer (score 2):

The following code will check if a folder already exists and if not creates one and warns you if error creating one:

```
    // check if appfolder is created and if not through an
    // exception
    File path = new File("yourDir");
    if (!path.exists()) {
        if (!path.mkdirs()) {
            try {
                throw new IOException(
                        "Application folder can not be created. Please check if your memory is writable and healthy and then try again.");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        Log.i("app", "directory is: " + path.getPath());
    }
```

`exists()` checks if a path exists or not and `path.exists()` simply creates one for you.